# Reference a model within a model in HTML for Django

Tags: django

I am trying to make a survey tool that has many questions within a model.

Here's what I embedded in my models page:

```
class Survey(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
content = models.TextField()
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Question(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
content = models.TextField()
survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is my survey view

```
class SurveyDetailView(DetailView):
model = Survey
```

And here is the HTML code for the survey detail view

```
 {%  for question in questions %}
    <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ question.title }}</a></h2>
{% endfor %}
```

While in my admin, there are several questions associated with a survey, it doesn't show this in the HTML when loaded. What am I missing here?

Comment: where from did you get questions, post your whole template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From DetailView [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview)

> While this view is executing, self.object will contain the object that
>   the view is operating upon.

in your case Survey is object to get questions use

```
 {%  for question in object.question_set.all %}
    <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ question.title }}</a></h2>
{% endfor %}
```

[many_to_one docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)